# print statements in dart-polymer UI not seen in webstorm console

Tags: dart, webstorm, dart-polymer

I have some print statements in a Dart UI app. Depending on the UI selection strings are printed to the console. Everything used to work as expected with with Dart with Eclipse plugin. Now I cannot see any print output to the console in my dart-polymer app.

Any possible help is appreciated.

### EDIT 1

#### .dart

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:paper_elements/paper_input.dart';
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

/// A Polymer `<main-app>` element.
@CustomTag('main-app')
class MainApp extends PolymerElement {
  @observable String reversed = '';

  /// Constructor used to create instance of MainApp.
  MainApp.created() : super.created();

  void reverseText(Event event, Object object, PaperInput target) {
    reversed = target.value.split('').reversed.join('');
    print(reversed); // NOTHING IS SHOWN IN ANY CONSOLE
  }
```

#### .html

```
<!-- import polymer-element's definition -->
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">

<link rel="import" href="../../packages/paper_elements/paper_input.html">

<polymer-element name="main-app">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>

    <paper-input label="Type something..." on-keyup="{{reverseText}}"></paper-input>

    <p>
      Reversed: {{ reversed }}
    </p>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="main_app.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

#### The print statement in main_app.dart DOES NOT PRINT TO ANY VISIBLE CONSOLE.

Comment: Can you provide any more information or example code? Unfortunately this isn't really enough to work with.

Comment: Are those print displayed on browser console?

Comment: With the eclipse plugin for Dart, the prints were displayed in eclipse console.

Comment: @Jake MacDonald Please see EDIT1

Comment: Did you install the IntelliJ debug plugin in Dartium?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer No. I will find it and install. Thanks

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks Gunter. I am now seeing a console with the expected output when the app when run in the debug mode after installing the plugin.

Comment: You wrote that Dart Eclipse plugin isn't supported on Windows anymore in a comment to a SO question a few days ago. How did you come to this conclusion? AFAIK it never was supported on Windows, but I assumed that it will be officially supported when the package_spec proposal is implemented, which is work in progress.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have the IntelliJ debug plugin installed in Dartium.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Simply running the app (as in Dart Editor) does not seem to be enough. In WebStorm, the print() statements appear in Console as expected only when I run the app in debug-mode (Ctrl-d).