# Print statements not showing in console in WebStorm while - Dart

Tags: dart, webstorm

So I'm new to Dart and WebStorm and I'm having trouble with the print statements. I have several print statements in my code, but when I run it, none of them appear.

Here's my code:

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  int choice = 0;
  String line;
  String firstName, lastName, contact;

  do {
    print("Please choose a number: /n");
    print("1 - Add a contact /n");
    print("2 - Edit a contact /n");
    print("3 - Look for a contact /n");
    print("0 - Exit application /n");

    line = stdin.readLineSync();
    choice = int.parse(line);

    switch (choice) {
      case 1:
       {
          print("Enter contact's first name: ");
          firstName = stdin.readLineSync();

          print("Enter contact's last name: ");
          lastName = stdin.readLineSync();

          print("Enter a contact number: ");
          contact = stdin.readByteSync();

          print("Is this an office or home contact?");
          print("Is this an office or home contact?");
        }

      case 0:
        {
          return 0;
        }
    }
  } while (choice > 3 || choice < 0);
}
```

The console shows this when I try to run it:

> C:\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe --ignore-unrecognized-flags --checked --enable-vm-service:51901 --trace_service_pause_events "C:\Users\myname\WebstormProjects\untitled\Test.dart"
>
> Process finished with exit code 254

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31122252

Comment: But I didn't use Dartium. Dart's site said it was optional. Do I have to use Dartium for it to work?

Comment: Sorry, I missed you're importing `dart:io`. I don't know what you could do wrong, always worked for me. Exit code 254 indicates the Dart code exited with an error. Maybe your print statements aren't executed at all.

Comment: I am pretty sure it should ne `\n` not `/n`?

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. But even without the \n, it does not show in the console.

Answer (score 0):

How are attempting to run the dart file? I just created a new Project and pasted your code in and right clicked on file and pressed run "filename".

Then, I recieved this

```
Please choose a number: /n
1 - Add a contact /n
2 - Edit a contact /n
3 - Look for a contact /n
0 - Exit application /n
```